# Rss in full text

Tags: scripting, rss-aggregator

I am looking for a way to extract the full text from an html file in the command line. The purpose of this is to make a blocklet for my i3 status bar.

I have found some site with names like "Full text RSS" but it always output a little html...

Comment: Is it possible to throw up an example of the information you'd be looking at, and what your end result should be? Some answers may be more complicated than others depending on the details.

Comment: I would like to get feeds from the BBC world news feed at http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml#.
The problem is that it contains a lot of feeds on an HTML page when I just need the last feed, only the title with the resume.

Comment: what language are you looking to use? I know that Python has a feedparser(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) module, I'm sure Perl/Ruby probably do as well. Using something along those lines may give you the most flexability

Comment: `rsstail -1u feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml#`

Comment: This is the tool ! Unfortunately I haven't succed installing libmrss in Archlinux with Yaourt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are scripts for html2text, but i think what you are looking for is xpath (e.g. xmllint supports it) to get the content of some elements of your html page.